# In R I want to select max timepoints, while grouping?

Tags: r, group-by, max, min, lag

I want to select the minimum `Timepoint`, maximum `Timepoint` and the duration (difference between max and min) grouped by `Replicate`, `Stimulus`, `Attribute` and `Complexity`

```
structure(list(Replicate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Stimulus = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Subject = c("S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", 
"S001", "S001"), Attribute = c("Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", 
"Soft", "Soft"), Timepoint = c(0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8, 0.81, 0.82
), Dominant = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Complexity = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using the following code

```
modified_tds_merged2<-tds_merged.df %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Timepoint = as.numeric(gsub("[a-zA-Z]+", "", Timepoint))) %>% 
  group_by(Replicate, Stimulus, Subject, Attribute, Complexity) %>% 
  summarise(
    start_time = min(Timepoint), 
    end_time = max(Timepoint),
    duration = end_time - start_time,
    n = n()
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

However the result is inncorrect, the endtimes are often incorrect as they overlap when ther can be only 1 `Complexity` rating at any `timepoint`, and seem random. Here is an example of the result. You can see that for S008, crumbly_particles, `Complexity` rating of 3 goes from `0.47 to 0.7`1 and `Complexity` rating of 4 goes from `0.51 to 0.66`. When I check back on `tds_merged.df`, `Complexity` rating 3 should be from `.47 to.50` and `.67 to .71`, and `Complexity` rating 4 is from `.51 to .66` which is correct. So it looks like my code doesn't specify that if the `Complexity` rating changes form 3 to 4 and back to 3, the two 3 ratings need to be calculated sperarately.

```
structure(list(Replicate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Stimulus = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Subject = c("S001", "S004", "S004", "S008", 
"S008", "S008"), Attribute = c("Soft", "Crumbly_Particles", "Soft", 
"Crumbly_Particles", "Crumbly_Particles", "Crunchy"), Complexity = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L), start_time = c(0.77, 0.95, 0.19, 0.47, 0.51, 
0.79), end_time = c(0.99, 0.99, 0.94, 0.71, 0.66, 0.82), duration = c(0.22, 
0.04, 0.75, 0.24, 0.15, 0.0299999999999999), n = c(23L, 5L, 76L, 
9L, 16L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Sorry for long "question"!! Hope someone can help. Maybe the problem is using max and min, is there another function, I am new to R?

Answer (score 0):

"So it looks like my code doesn't specify that if the Complexity rating changes".  Correct.  `group_by` sorts your data (whether explicitly or implicitly is not always clear, but that's another story).  So your solution is to introduce another variable, `RunID` for example, that changes every time `Complexity` changes within `Replicate`, `Stimulus`, `Subject` and `Attribute`.

Comment: OK thank you. So with the new `RunID` column, what would I use to show the complexity rating changes, if it has the same complexity rating values in it would I not have the same problem?

Comment: Also where I have always been unsure is what to use instead of `max` and `min` to identify the `complexity` changes.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above I used the `rleid` function to creat a new group ID variable to allow for the situation in my question.